# sudo apt update errors on PUBKEY Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

The error states:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Machine info:

```
Linux abt33 5.4.0-167-generic #184-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 31 09:21:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I have tried a number of suggestions from around stackoverflow etc: I have tried the following with no success:

```
sudo curl http://repo.ros2.org/repos.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://dl.k8s.io/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
wget -O - https://apt.kitware.com/keys/kitware-archive-latest.asc 2>/dev/null | gpg --dearmor - | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu/ focal main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kitware.list >/dev/null
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_pzz.gpg > /dev/null
```

```
sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/kitware-archive-keyring.gpg followed by
sudo apt-get install kitware-archive-keyring
```

Here are my keys:

```
apt-key list /etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2020-03-02 [SC] [expires: 2024-03-01]
      F640 3F65 44A3 8863 DAA0  B6E0 3F01 618A 5131 2F3F
uid           [ unknown] GitLab B.V. (package repository signing key) <packages@gitlab.com>
sub   rsa4096 2020-03-02 [E] [expires: 2024-03-01]

pub   dsa1024 2003-02-03 [SCA] [expired: 2022-02-16]
      A4A9 4068 76FC BD3C 4567  70C8 8C71 8D3B 5072 E1F5
uid           [ expired] MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>

pub   rsa4096 2019-05-30 [SC] [expires: 2025-06-01]
      C1CF 6E31 E6BA DE88 68B1  72B4 F42E D6FB AB17 C654
uid           [ unknown] Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_pzz.gpg
-----------------------------------
pub   rsa2048 2019-11-30 [SC] [expires: 2024-04-23]
      CDE7 95FF 222A BFA5 503F  6E49 23E0 7629 B9E3 C9E4
uid           [ unknown] home:pzz OBS Project <home:pzz@build.opensuse.org>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
      F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

Nothing seems to work. Anyone have a solution?
Thanks.

Comment: You just need to get the updated key for the MySQL repository from MySQL then you can add that to your system and it should work.  The only MySQL key you have there is a very old one that expired in 2022, and you just need a replacement/updated key

Answer (score 0):

Turns out. This seems to have done the trick.

curl https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022 | sudo apt-key add -